# Error Spring MVC Rest Full

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, restful

Boa noite,

Estou tentando compilar um código para rodar um simples rest no spring mvc, porém encontrei com o erro "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."

Class Controller

```
package br.com.aprendendorest.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import br.com.aprendendorest.models.cliente;
import br.com.aprendendorest.repository.clienteRepository;

@RestController
public class clienteController {

    @Autowired
    clienteRepository clienteService;

    @GetMapping("/cliente")
    public ResponseEntity<List<cliente>> listCliente() {
        System.out.println("Entro Get");
        List<cliente> clientes = clienteService.listAll();
        return new ResponseEntity<List<cliente>>(clientes, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    @PostMapping("/cliente")
    public ResponseEntity<cliente> creatCliente(@RequestBody cliente cli) {
        System.out.println("Entro no POST");
        System.out.println("ID: " + cli.getId() + ", NOME: " + cli.getNome() + ", EMAIL: " + cli.getEmail());
        clienteService.addCliente(cli);
        return new ResponseEntity<cliente>(cli, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

Classe Model

```
package br.com.aprendendorest.models;

public class cliente {
    private Integer id;
    private String nome;
    private String email;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public cliente(int id, String nome, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

POST JSON

```
{
    "id": 5,
    "nome": "Marcos",
    "email": "teste"
}
```

Print da Requisição
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como está sendo feita a requisição?

Comment: Através do Postman, usando o json acima, com o content type application/json.

Comment: Ok, compartilha uma print da sua requisição no postman

Comment: Editei o Post @Leonardo Villela, não entendo pois os campos e tipos estão corretos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que esteja relacionado ao fato do seu model não ter um construtor publico,que não receba nenhum argumento e também não estar implementando a interface`Serializable`, realizando esses 2 passos, sua classe se torna um POJO(Plain Old Java Object), padrão a qual o Jackson(responsável pela serialização de objetos) necessita que seja seguido para conseguir realizar a serialização sem nenhuma annotation de customização.

Referencia relacionada ao assunto POJO: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Objects

Comment: Obrigado Leonardo, realmente foi a falta dos 2 passos citados na sua resposta, estou aprendendo e vou estudar mais sobre a classe Serializable e também sobre o POJO.

Comment: Blz, que bom que consegui te ajudar.